# Change the order of the child components in angular 2 while rendering on the fly

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

I'm a bit new to the angular 2 world so please excuse me if it's a naive question.

I want to read a json file which contains the meta for various components that I need to display for a page.

I need to read this json and render the child components in the order they are listed here.

I've successfully used dynamic component loader API that angular 2 provides to dynamically load the child components inside a for loop. However, there are some other requirements that make the use of this API a bit complex.

So I'm looking for another way to do the same thing. It'd be like manipulating the DOM from within the ts file of the parent component to get the child components in the same order as mentioned in the JSON.

Any leads would be very helpful.
Thanks a lot!

PS: sorry for not publishing the code. I've Posted this using my mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `DynamicComponentLoader` (deprecated in favor of `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` with the same restrictions) I see only the option of using an element that wraps all possible components and renders only the one that is selected

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper-component',
  directives: [Cmp1, Cmp2, Cmp3, ... Cmp10],
  template: `
    <div [ngSwitch]="type">
      <cmp1 *ngSwitchCase="'cmp1'"></cmp1>
      <cmp2 *ngSwitchCase="cmp2"></cmp2>
      <cmp3 *ngSwitchCase="cmp3"></cmp3>
      ....
      <cmp10 *ngSwitchCase="cmp4"></cmp4>
      <div *ngSwitchDefault>not supported</div>
    </div>
`})
export class WrapperComponent {
  @Input() type:string;
}
```

and use it like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-cmp',
  template: `
    <wrapper-component *ngFor="let item of someJson" [type]="item.componentName"></wrapper-component>
  `})
export class ParentComponent {
  someJson; // assign the JSON here
}
```